# How do I find the offset of an ext4 filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, partition, data-recovery, ext4

I have a failing hard drive that is unable to write or read the first sectors of the disk. It just gives I/O errors and that is all there is. There are other areas on the disk that seem (mostly) fine.
I am trying to mount a partition (ext4) and see if I can access some files I would like to recover. Since the `mount` command supports an `offset` option, I should be able to mount the filesystem even though the partition table is unreadable and unwriteable. The problem is how to find the offset. None of the ext4 tools seems to have this particular feature.

Comment: Try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and the accompanying photorec.

Comment: @jippie it took testdisk 6 hours to scan the whole disk and in the end it didn't find any partition. i think the best strategy is to try to find the location of the filesystem directly and mount it.

Comment: photorec will probably be able to get your files off the disk, but filenames and pathnames will be lost. If you manage to mount the filesystem that is of course your better option, but if testdisk didn't find any, chances are that the start of the filesystem is corrupted too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There isn't a standard offset per-se, as of course you can start the partition wherever you want. But let's assume for a moment that you're looking for the first partition, and it was created more or less accepting defaults. There are then two places you may find it, assuming you were using a traditional DOS partition table:

1. Starting at (512-byte) sector 63. This was the tradition for a very long time, and worked until someone came up with 4K disks...
2. Starting at (512-byte) sector 2048. This is the new tradition, to accommodate 4K disks.
3. A bonus option! Sarting at sector 56. This is what happens if someone moves the 63-start partition to make it align with a 4K sector.

Now, to proceed, you'll want to pick up your favorite hex-dump tool, and learn a little about the [ext4 Disk Layout](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout). In particular, it starts with 1024 bytes of padding, which ext4 ignores. Next comes the superblock. You can recognize the superblock by checking for the magic number 0xEF53 at offset 0x38 (from the superblock start, or 0x438 from the partition start, or 1080 in decimal.) The **magic number is little-endian.** So it's actually stored on disk as 0x53EF.

Here is what that looks like with `xxd -a`:

`0000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
*
0000400: 0040 5d00 0084 7401 33a0 1200 33db a600  .@]...t.3...3...
0000410: 4963 5300 0000 0000 0200 0000 0200 0000  IcS.............
0000420: 0080 0000 0080 0000 0020 0000 6637 0952  ......... ..f7.R
0000430: 6637 0952 0200 1600 53ef 0100 0100 0000  f7.R....S.......
0000440: 9938 f851 004e ed00 0000 0000 0100 0000  .8.Q.N..........`

Note, that when you give the offset to mount (or losetup), you must give the offset to where the padding starts—not the superblock.

Now, if its not the first partition, or otherwise isn't in one of the two (three) expected spots, you basically get to search for the magic number 0xEF53. This is what `testdisk` (recommended in a comment) does for you.

Comment: SUCCESS!!! I had to write my own script. `testdisk` wouldn't find it. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Based on this, you can use something like `dd if=/dev/sda skip=$start_sector | xxd -a | grep '[02468]30: .... .... .... .... 53ef'` to get some probable matches.  Probably not very fast, but you can let it run while you find a better method.

Comment: See my answer below for the "better method" now.  Note: just scanning for this number in random data will find a false positive every 65536 sectors (32 MB).

Comment: thanks for this. due to the fact it took me a second read to notice `testdisk`, i just had to add an edit for a `tl;dr:` header

Comment: Calling (3) "bonus option" made my day :-)

Answer (score 5):

Based on [@derobert's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103931/38647), I wrote a program ([gist](https://gist.github.com/countingpine/0fd04b99058ebc910fefc910606ae6d0)) that will parse an input stream from `dd` and scan each sector for something that looks like the start of an ext partition.

It will work at least as fast as `dd` can read from your hard disk.  An abridged version is below.

The simplest usage is just `sudo dd if=/dev/xxx | ext2scan`, although you will likely want to modify the `dd` command to improve the block size or choose a region to search.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  unsigned char const MAGIC[2] = {0x53, 0xef};
  unsigned char const ZEROS[512] = {0};

  long long int sector = 0;

  char buf[4][512];
  int empty1, empty2;

  while (read(STDIN_FILENO, buf[sector&3], 512) > 0) {
    if (!memcmp(buf[sector&3] + 0x38, MAGIC, 2)) {
      printf("Found a possible ext2 partition at sector %lld", sector-2);

      empty1 = !memcmp(buf[(sector-2)&3], ZEROS, 512);
      empty2 = !memcmp(buf[(sector-1)&3], ZEROS, 512);

      if (empty1 && empty2) printf(" (first two sectors are empty :)\n");
    }
    sector++;
  }
}
```

Note: it will find not just the start of partitions, but also [superblocks](http://www.science.unitn.it/~fiorella/guidelinux/tlk/node97.html) within them.

In either case, I would recommend using [`dumpe2fs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dumpe2fs) to analyse the results.  You can dump the start of the suspected superblock to a file (at least the first six sectors, according to my informal test), and if it is a superblock, then `dumpe2fs` will tell you (among other things) the relative locations of the other superblocks.

Comment: Maybe use dd options `iflag=direct bs=1M` to speed up reads.

Answer (score 3):

Make a guess as to where the partition starts and apply some brute force:

```
bsz=512 # or 1024, 2048, 4096 higher = faster

for i in {2..10000000}; do
    echo "--->$i<---"
    mount -o offset=$(($bsz*$i)) -t ext4 /dev/whatever /mnt/foo
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then # whahoo!
        echo Eureka
        break
    fi
done
```

I imagine this could take some time, but if you've already spent 6 hours with testdisk, maybe it is worth a try.

Comment: Hah, that is a lot of brute force!

Comment: It works but it is slow; I tried this on an multi-partition image whose offsets I knew, so I could start it fairly close.  Threw in the `echo "--->$i<---"` line because of that since otherwise it's impossible to gauge the progress.  I think you could increase `bsz` to 4096, which will speed things up.

Comment: You could speed it up a lot if you assume traditional layout where partitions start on a "track" (or is it cylinder?) boundary.

Comment: my estimate was to poor for this solution to be practical but can work in other circumstances

Answer (score 2):

Try different option (eg, using debugfs, and fsck.ext4):

debugfs:

You have to mount debugfs first (not the failing harddisk itself):

http://johnsofteng.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sysfs-procfs-sysctl-debugfs-and-other-similar-kernel-interfaces/

http://afzalkhanlinuxtalk.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/how-to-recover-deleted-file-in-linux/comment-page-1/#comment-8

http://blesseddlo.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/using-debugfs/

(essentially, is to use "debugfs -w" with write-enabled mode, and then followed by "lsdel" to list out all the deleted files).   alternatively you can use

and here is fsck.ext4:

http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/

Another is "sleuthkit" ("sudo apt-get install sleuthkit") which have command like "istat" for providing blocks info about the inodes - from which you can get the offset and thus block data content easily.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/linux/l-cn-ext4resize/

(BTW, if the blocksize is 1024, from debugfs's "show_super_stats" command, then it follows that block 1 is 1024 bytes offset from start of the disk, and each block group can have several blocks too.)

Answer (score 1):

I had an e-book firmware image which included ext3fs partition image, in order to mount and edit that I had to scan image using [bgrep tool](https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep) to find all positions of ext3fs magic number `0x53EF` and try to mount using found offsets.

Here is a shortened script which performs mounting:

```
#!/bin/sh
FW_IMAGE=$1
MOUNT_POINT=$2

FS_TYPE=ext3
EXTFS_MAGIC_NUM=53ef
MAGIC_OFFSET=1080

OFFSETS=`bgrep $EXTFS_MAGIC_NUM $FW_IMAGE | awk '{print toupper($NF)}'`
for OFFSET in $OFFSETS; do
  OFFSET=`echo "ibase=16; $OFFSET" | bc`
  OFFSET=`expr $OFFSET - $MAGIC_OFFSET`
  sudo mount -t $FS_TYPE -o loop,offset=$OFFSET $FW_IMAGE $MOUNT_POINT 2>/dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Success!  Offset is: $OFFSET."
    break
  fi
done
```

[Complete script located here](https://gist.github.com/iwakura/ff478c8c4ba9add94fe5464f30f9a009).

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem recently and I came up with a regexp to find candidate superblocks. It seems that grep is somewhat awkward when it comes to searching binary data, but the following worked for me:

```
LANG=C grep --only-matching --byte-offset --binary --text --perl-regexp '\x53\xEF[\x00-\x07]\x00[\x01-\x03]\x00' "${fs_file}"
```

Then **subtract 0x38** from the printed offsets to get the address of a potential superblock.

Note that the above regexp also looks at some bytes that come after the magic bytes. According [to ext4 documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/globals.html) these bytes contain flags (`super_state` and `super_errors`) that can only ever have certain values.

Of course there are many more well-known values in the superblock. So this regexp can easily be extended. But the above worked for me to prevent too many false positives.

On the other hand, this approach might miss a superblock, if those particular bytes are damaged.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but I think you can use the method discussed in this SU Q&A titled: [Reverse lookup of inode/file from offset in raw device on linux and ext3/4?](https://superuser.com/questions/490787/reverse-lookup-of-inode-file-from-offset-in-raw-device-on-linux-and-ext3-4).

It looks like you can use a file's inode + the disks offset + block size to determine a file's offset.

Comment: i don't see how this method could help me to figure out where the file system starts.