# How do I recover an ext4 volume overwritten by an LVM logical volume?

Tags: partition, lvm, data-recovery

I was running an Ubuntu desktop. The OS was installed on a SSD. I had two additional drives formatted ext4 and mounted on /storage (1TB) and /storage-bak (1.5TB).

I installed Centos over Ubuntu on the SSD and the install put a 2.3GB Logical volume on my two "storage" drives.  I didn't want this.  I guess I missed something during the Centos install.

Centos used the LV to mount /home on it.  I booted once and logged in.  Not much was written to it.
Is there any way to remove the LV and get my drives back to the state they were in.... data intact?

I just want a /dev/sdb1 and a /dev/sdc1  so I can mount them as generic EXT4 drives.

Comment: first: shut down your computer **immediately. do it _right now._** minimizing the amount of time that goes by after data loss is critical to ensure that a minimal amount of data gets overwritten.

Comment: I've removed the two drive from the volume group.  They are not mounted or used in the VG anymore.

However, I need to get the original partition info on them so I can remount them.

Answer (score 1):

There was [a good answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103919/how-do-i-find-the-offset-of-an-ext4-filesystem/103931#103931) yesterday regarding recovery under somewhat different circumstances.  You might well be able to make a reasonable guess about where your previous partitions were and apply that method to find the exact offset, then try and mount them.

It is possible that reformatting the drive destroyed the old superblock, but this is backed up, and the chances of the backups all being gone seem slim.  [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), recommended by various people, apparently can find them.  That seems like a good place to start.

Once you've recovered your data you can use a combination of `fdisk` and `parted` or `gparted` to rearrange stuff back to the way you want it.  In my experience with (g)parted you may need to delete everything but the first partition in order to resize it, and fdisk may be a bit more flexible about deleting and creating partitions.

Remember to update your `/etc/fstab` if you get rid of the `/home` partition.  IMO it's a bit stupid that distros by default now do this (creating partitions for `/home`, `/usr`, etc).  `/boot` partitions are not really necessary either.  But que sera -- pay attention ;)

Comment: I tried testdisk.  It found the partitions but they were empty.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a live CD (or usb) of parted magic. Boot into that and make a full image copy of the disk to another drive using dd

`dd if=/dev/sdx of=/path/to/image`

If you don't have another disk, you'll likely have to skip this procecure.

Use photorec to try to recover your files (in the menu of parted magic).

Comment: I tried creating an ISO.  When I tried to mount the iso I got the same error as trying to mount the drive.  

mount -o loop /mnt/sdc.iso /media/ 


mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'